# How to statically link a library originally intended to be used as a Tcl extension?

Tags: tcl

I have a library, originally built as a loadable Tcl extension. I'm now trying to use it for a slightly different purpose (an interactive shell with libtecla for tab-completion and history) and am currently failing to get the `Tcl_StaticPackage()` and `load {} $lib` combination to work. Strangely, while not working, it also doesn't produce an error.

I've reduced the code required to demonstrate the problem to:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tcl.h>

extern "C" {
    int Demolib_Init(Tcl_Interp *);
    int Demolib_SafeInit(Tcl_Interp *);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Tcl_Interp *interp;

    interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();

    if (!interp)
    {
        perror("Couldn't create interpreter");
        return 1;
    }

    if (TCL_OK != Tcl_Init(interp))
    {
        perror("Couldn't initialize Tcl");
        return 2;
    }

    Tcl_StaticPackage(interp, "Demolib", Demolib_Init, Demolib_SafeInit);

    printf("Via 'load'...\n");
    if (TCL_OK != Tcl_Eval(interp, "load {} Demolib"))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Err : %s\n", Tcl_GetStringResult(interp));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Ok  : %s\n", Tcl_GetStringResult(interp));
    }

    printf("\nVia 'Demolib_Init()'...\n");
    Demolib_Init(interp);

    return 0;
}
```

**demolib.cpp**

```
#include <tcl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "demolib.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int DLLEXPORT Demolib_Init(Tcl_Interp *interp)
{
    printf("Pre-stubs\n");

#ifdef USE_TCL_STUBS
    if (Tcl_InitStubs(interp, TCL_VERSION, 0) == NULL)
    {
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }
#endif

    printf("Pre-provide\n");

    if (Tcl_PkgProvide(interp, "Demolib", "0.0") == TCL_ERROR)
    {
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }

    printf("Pre-return\n");

    return TCL_OK;
}

int DLLEXPORT Demolib_SafeInit(Tcl_Interp *interp)
{
    return Demolib_Init(interp);
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

(While the demo has no need to be a .cpp, the real code does)

If `"Demolib"` below does not match the library name in the `load {} ...`, an error is raised, so `Tcl_StaticPackage()` is having an effect that `load` can see.

```
    Tcl_StaticPackage(interp, "Demolib", Demolib_Init, Demolib_SafeInit);
    ...
    if (TCL_OK != Tcl_Eval(interp, "load {} Demolib"))
```

However, neither `Demolib_Init()` or `Demolib_SafeInit()` is ever called. I *can* call it directly, and it could be said to be neater (no `Tcl_Eval(...)` call), but I'd like to understand what's (not) happening. In the final application, the timing of the `load {} ...` will be determined by a script, so this functionality is required.

Note that I am deliberately not calling `Tcl_Main()` or entering the Tcl event loop - libtecla will eventually be providing a prompt.

What have I missed?

Comment: I think it's something to do with how it is built and linked, but this is an area I don't know well.

Comment: That's a shame - I was confidently anticipating one of your usual comprehensive explanations. What I didn't make clear is that while the file solution will preferably be statically link to the library, in this simplified case I am just linking two .o's into an executable.

Comment: The above comment should say *"... while the final solution ..."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying this on Windows using MSVC 2013 and Tcl 8.6 using the two files provided:

```
C:\src\Files\DemoTcl>cl -nologo -I/opt/tcl/include -D_DEBUG -Od -Zi -MDd -c main.cpp
main.cpp

C:\src\Files\DemoTcl>cl -nologo -I/opt/tcl/include -D_DEBUG -Od -Zi -MDd -c demolib.cpp
demolib.cpp

C:\src\Files\DemoTcl>link -nologo -subsystem:console main.obj demolib.obj \opt\tcl\lib\tcl86.lib
   Creating library main.lib and object main.exp

C:\src\Files\DemoTcl>main.exe
Via 'load'...
Ok  :

Via 'Demolib_Init()'...
Pre-stubs
Pre-provide
Pre-return
```

If we change the Tcl_StaticPackage call to the following:

```
    Tcl_StaticPackage(NULL, "Demolib", Demolib_Init, Demolib_SafeInit);
```

Then the new executable output is:

```
Via 'load'...
Pre-stubs
Pre-provide
Pre-return
Ok  :

Via 'Demolib_Init()'...
Pre-stubs
Pre-provide
Pre-return
```

I think you are supposed to add a `Tcl_FindExecutable(argv[0]);` really early on as well although this doesn't affect the problem presented.

The documentation for Tcl_StaticPackage subtly points out that the interp argument points to an interpreter where the package has already been loaded if it is not NULL.

Comment: hmm - seems like it should have printed out Pre-provide and so on immediately after "Via 'load'". So not ok then.

Comment: ok - you need to use NULL in the Tcl_StaticPackage call. See edit.

Comment: Excellent Pat, thanks. It seems my reading of the docs in this case was reduced to the slightly inadequate "Tcl_Interp * - I've got one of those!"

Comment: Now _that_ is subtle! +1